# next,closest selector is not working Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi in the following html , jquery next and closest selector is not working
 .

```
 <div>
   <div class="class1" style=" background-color: red"> hi </div>
   <br>
   <div class="class2">Yes</div>
</div>
```

when i try `alert ($(".class1").next(".class2").text())`,  `alert ($(".class1").closest(".class2").text())` both alerting blank .I need to alert **yes** .

What is the error in the code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` is the `<br>` not the element with class `.class2`. Use another `next()`:

```js
alert($(".class1").next().next(".class2").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="class1" style=" background-color: red">hi</div>
  <br>
  <div class="class2">Yes</div>
</div>
```

If there are multiple `<br>` elements you can use `nextAll()`:

```js
alert($(".class1").nextAll(".class2").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="class1" style=" background-color: red">hi</div>
  <br>
  <div class="class2">Yes</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The divs with class1 and class2 are at the same level in the dom. So you could look within the siblings of class1 and search for class2.

```
$(".class1").siblings('.class2').text()
// => "Yes"
```

Or you could use the parent element of both to find the class2 under it.

```
$(".class1").parent().find('.class2').text()
// => "Yes"
```

Answer (score 2):

`next` only looks at the next immediate sibling. What you want is [`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```js
console.log($(".class1").nextAll(".class2").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <div class="class1" style=" background-color: red"> hi </div>
   <br>
   <div class="class2">Yes</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As `next()` only target immediately following sibling thus your code didn't worked.

You can get `.parent()` then use `.find()`/`.children()`.

```
$(".class1").parent('div').find(".class2").text()
```

```js
console.log($(".class1").parent('div').find(".class2").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="class1" style=" background-color: red">hi</div>
  <br>
  <div class="class2">Yes</div>
</div>
```